# Add to parentclass's class attribute in subclass

Tags: python, inheritance

I may be on the wrong path here, so if my approach to this is bogus, please advice.

Basically I have a class that has a dictionary containing printing information for every property. I create a child of this class that adds another property:

```
class A(object):

    _print_dict = {"a": "ms"}

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 5

    def __str__(self):
        s = ""
        for attr in self._print_dict:
            s += "{} {}\n".format(getattr(self, attr), _print_dict[attr])
        return s

class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.b = 10
```

I could update in `B.__init__`, but that would make `_print_dict`a instance attribute, right?

```
class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.b = 10
        self._print_dict.update({"b": "V"})
```

When trying to access `_print_dict` outside `__init__` however, i get a `NameError`:

```
class B(A):

    _print_dict.update({"b": "V"})

    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.b = 10
```

The same obviously happens with `self._print_dict`, since `self` is not defined when the class is created (I presume).

Is there a way to alter the class attribute `_print_dict` in the subclass `B`? Without altering it for class `A` as well?

### Edit:

I obviously missed using the parent class's name explicitly:

```
class B(A):

    _print_dict = A._print_dict.copy()
    _print_dict.update({"b": "V"})

    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.b = 10
```

Is this the way to do it? At least it seems to work...

Comment: somehow you managed to read my mind while I was typing my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the dictionary in `B.__init__` would not make it an instance attribute. Instead, you would modify the same dictionary each time you make an instance of `B`:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     _print_dict = {"a": "ms"}
...
>>> class B(A):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self._print_dict.update({"b": "V"})
...
>>> A._print_dict is B._print_dict
True # they are the same object
>>> A._print_dict
{'a': 'ms'} # not yet updated
>>> b = B()
>>> A._print_dict is B._print_dict is b._print_dict
True # still the same object
>>> A._print_dict
{'a': 'ms', 'b': 'V'}
```

If you want to preserve the original dictionary in `A`, you have to copy it in the class definition of `B`. Dictionaries convieniently have a method for this:

```
>>> class B(A):
...     _print_dict = A._print_dict.copy()
...     _print_dict.update({'b': 'V'})
...
>>> A._print_dict is B._print_dict
False # now they are two distinct objects
>>> A._print_dict
{'a': 'ms'}
>>> B._print_dict
{'a': 'ms', 'b': 'V'}
```

Comment: Even more convenient could be `_print_dict = dict(A._print_dict, b='V')`